How to convexify this non-convex constraint using successive convex approximation (SCA)?
I have the following constraint
$\left( {\sum\limits_{l = 1,l \ne i}^I {{V_l}} } \right) - \frac{{{V_i}}}{{{u_i}}} + c{I_N}\underline  \succ  0$,
where $c>0$ is a constant scalar, $I_N$ is a identity matrix with $N$ dimension.
The optimization variables are ${\left\{ {{V_l}} \right\}_{l = 1, \cdots ,I}}$ and $u_i$, where
${{V_l}}$ is a positive semidefinite matrix with $N$ dimension and $u_i>0$ is a scalar.
The division term $\frac{{{V_i}}}{{{u_i}}}$ makes this constraint non-convex, so how to convexify this term using SCA so that the whole constraint is convex?

Just want to ask if you are 100% sure that the denominator $u_i$ is trictly greater than zero ?
